# Creating a Forum - Doesn't Show Who Posted

Tags: php

So I am creating basics scripts for a basic forum and with my function to grab the owners name, it doesn't display. Although when I make a new post, it actually posts the users ID of who posted it in the database as the wrong ID even though I am logged in through Session. Maybe I have some error with my session. Lemme know what you think.

Check if logged in:

```
  session_start();
  ob_start();
    include('../connect.php');
    include('qa_func.php');
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    } else {
```

Get owner func:

```
function getOwner($id){
    $q = @mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
    if(!$q){
        echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
    } else {
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        $name = $res['username'];
    }
    return $name;
}
```

Than to get the owners name I'd just do this:

```
getOwner($res['topic_by'])
```

There is no problem with it fetching the users ID its just that by default when I post it sets it as ID: 17 for some reason. But if I change the ID to 8 which is a real users ID than it will show that username.

It is deffinitely a problem with when it posts.

If you need more code just let me know.

Edit: I forgot to add the code where it inputs the users ID when posting.

```
$qt = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO topics VALUES ('', \"$subject\",now(),'$cat','$id')");
if(!$qt){
    echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
}

$qst = @mysql_query("SELECT topic_id FROM topics WHERE topic_subject='$subject'");
if(!$qst){
    echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
}

$res=mysql_fetch_array($qst);
$topicId= $res['topic_id'];

$qr = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO replies VALUES('', \"$comment\", now(), '$topicId', '$id')");
if(!$qr){
    echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
}
```

http://gyazo.com/8ae6fcc5ed10098242d88600d5f41413
http://gyazo.com/6daeca3baf8b656adaa3f3edd926507b.png

Login Script:

```
$details = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$usr = $details['username'];

$pass = $details['password'];

$id = $details['id'];

if($pass == $password){

$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

Comment: Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Where do you assign the `$id` variable that you're using for the `INSERT INTO topics` call? What is the database structure? Can you post some sample data from it?

Comment: I added this in the function above the query. "$id = $_SESSION['id'];" And yeah thats no problem Ill screenshot the structure and show an example of the output when I post something.

Comment: Are you sure that $_SESSION['id'] is being set properly? Can you try echoing out your SQL queries, to make sure they're being defined correctly - you just need to `echo` them. And your using `INSERT INTO table VALUES` - I always include the fieldnames in there, too, as it's all too easy to omit one value.

Comment: Updated the post with the screenshots. Also if I echo $id on the new_topic page it shows this: 20 when my ID is 8 on the account Im signed into. Also for some reason my new posts now post the data to the database as 20, used to be 17 now 20, weird...

Comment: It looks like you're not setting `$_SESSION['id']` properly, in that case - could you add that code, too, please?

Comment: Updated the post with how it stores it as a session.

Comment: Is `$id` set properly when you log in? If you echo out it just before you set it in $_SESSION, is it showing up as 8 or 20? And do you have `session_start()` included at the top of each page?

Comment: Yes and its showing 20 if I echo before I set $ID in $_SESSION. And I updated my post with the loginscript.

Comment: So the database query is returning an incorrect value. Can you try a `var_dump($details)` to see what it's producing? And try echoing out the SQL you've got in `$query`, too.

Comment: Side note, mysql_ functions are deprecated.  Using mysqli or PDO is strongly recommended.  Prepared statements will prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Andrew, where do you want me to do this? We've talked about 5 different scripts throughout this. @Matt, this error actually isn't even with the database, its through session but yeah I use MYSQLi for everything but this is just a test script.

Comment: By the way, it is only this forum section of the website that it is showing ID of 20, on the rest of my website it works fine. http://codeeplus.ml/ Try it yourself if you'd like.

Comment: @KevinHarrison - you need to debug your login code. It's setting `$id` to 20 when it should be 8 - have you checked the database to make sure that you don't have multiple accounts?